# python class definition Vs C++ class definition

Tags: c++, python, class, definition

I just observed how the classes  are different in python when compared with C++.
Like,
In C++

```
Class test

{


    int  a,b;

    Void  func()

    {

    }  

}
```

In the above class template, a and b are only Object variables which are defined in the template.

Whereas, in python,  you can’t specify what and all the object variables  the class can have in class definition.

Like,

```
Class student(self):

    def func(self,x)
        pass
```

In the above class template, we can’t  define  any Object variables .  dir (student) will give a list of  functions and class variables only.

suppose if am instantiating an object of this class, Say, S. If I want to give a name to that student then,
                        S.name = “ “ will do

Now dir(S) will show the name attribute whereas dir(student) won’t have a name field
For me it sounded a little weird .

The interpreting feature of python allows to add  as many fields as we want to the object that's fine.

questions that came to me was

1. why they didn’t provided the feature of defining variables  in class definition? , And
2. how the memories are reserved during instantiation and modified when new variables are added to the objects?

Thanks,

-kallis

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: There are exactly no "templates" anywhere in the post.

Answer (score 2):

1. Python emphasizes dynamic typing, so you can add variables whenever you want. You can add any variables you want to be there in the `__init__` constructor. You also might want [class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python). If you *really* want, you can override [the `__setattr__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) to stop people from adding new attributes. You could also use [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots), but [you shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/python-slots).
2. If you don't use `__slots__`, attributes are stored in the `__dict__` dictionary. So a class instance itself takes only the space of a dictionary pointer (plus a few other small things).